# How to animate an unknown number of items in sequence using css animations?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a grid of items, that I'd like to animate so that they come in a certain order, but I don't know in advance how many items I will have. Items should appear according to the diagonal they're in. So, in the example grid below, cell 1 should come in first, then cells numbered 2, and so on.

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
```

I know I can just set the animation delay using javascript, but is there a pure css way to do this?

Comment: There's no CSS only solution I believe.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, You might be able to use nth-child() math to 'absolute' position items in the correct order but I'm not sure.. if you could give specific class names before rendering it'd be much easier

Comment: But can you somehow accesss that 'n' of nth-child?

Comment: I might be able to 'solve' the problem by just loading them in at n rows at a time. There's only so many rows that will fit on a screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use wow.js and set the offsets using data attributes.